# Hi, I've just started learning python. How do i replace characters in a string

Tags: python, string

So here's the string **"Where are you? Meet me near the clock tower."**

Now there are a total of **9 words**. And I've to consider **3 pairs**, each containing **3 consecutive words** from the start of the string.

So here's the thing, I have to replace the vowels in the first word with **"%"**, consonants in the second word with **"#"** and the last word must be converted to uppercase. And they should concatenate with each other.

The output should look like this
Wh%r%a#eYOU?M%%t#eNEARth%##o##TOWER.

Here's what i've tried

```
def replaceVowelsWithK(s1, K):
    vow = 'AEIUOaeiou'
    for ele in vow:
        s1 = s1.replace(ele, K)
    return s1
    
def replaceConsWithX(s2, x): 
    cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    for con in cons:
        s2= s2.replace(con, "#")
    return s2
    
def replaceVowelsWithK(s4, K):
    vow = 'AEIUOaeiou'
    for ele in vow:
        s4 = s4.replace(s4, K)
    return s4
    
    
def replaceConsWithX(s5, x): 
    cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    for con in cons:
        s5= s5.replace(con, "#")
    return s5

def replaceVowelsWithK(s7, K):
    vow = 'AEIUOaeiou'
    for ele in vow:
        s7 = s7.replace(ele, K)
    return s7
    
def replaceConsWithX(s8, x): 
    cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    for con in cons:
        s8= s8.replace(con, "#")
    return s8
    
s1 = "Where"
s2="are"
s3='you?'
s4="Meet"
s5="me"
s6="near"
s7="the"
s8="clock"
s9="tower"
K="%"
x="#"

x1=replaceVowelsWithK(s1, K)
x2=replaceConsWithX(s2, x)
x3=s3.upper()
x4=replaceVowelsWithK(s4, K)
x5=replaceConsWithX(s5, x)
x6=s6.upper()
x7=replaceVowelsWithK(s7, K)
x8=replaceConsWithX(s8, x)
x9=s9.upper()
result=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9
print(result)
```

The code gets too long.
And I just need to have a single input string "Where are you? Meet me near the clock tower."
Is there an easy way to do this? Like splitting the string and using a common function for substrings?

Comment: you define e.g. `replaceConsWithX` several times (for `s5` and `s8`) this is not necessary. Think of math functions like `sin(x)` you don't define them new for every possible variable name. Choose one parameter name, e.g. `s` it will catch all variable names that it is called with.

Comment: "Like splitting the string.." Yes, such a function exists and is almost named like this too. Just do a bit more research next time and you'll find the solutions by yourself probably.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context ? Like why would such a script be used for, for instance.

Comment: No particular reason. I've just started learning python and last week I had watched a tutorial about strings and lists. I just want to apply whatever I'm currently learning. So I was just searching for some string based problems and then I stumbled upon this one. I've been trying to solve it for a week. Like I even tried using split() as suggested by trilarion and append() but wasn'table to solve it.

Comment: So instead of wasting any more time I asked the question over here. This problem did got resolved and I appreciate it. But still, I think there are other ways to do it. If possible I would like others to provide me with just hints because I think I'll be able to learn more rather than full blown solutions haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
st = "Where are you? Meet me near the clock tower"
ls = st.split()
word = ""
for i in range(len(ls)):
    if i%3 == 0:
        t = ls[i]
        for j in "aeiou":
            t = t.replace(j, "%")
        word += t
    elif i%3 == 1:
        t = ls[i]
        for j in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
            t = t.replace(j, "#")
        word += t
    else:
        word += ls[i].upper()

print(word)
```

Try this by splitting string into a list and then change words according to  it.